# Arrow is not touching to nodes in d3.js tree view in mobile and touch screen

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, d3.js

We have used d3 tree with so many nodes(multilevel). Arrows looks perfect working in browser but not working with touch. how to resolve this issue in such way that arrow should touch node? Nodes used are rectangular as given in this question. arrow is working currently double click[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMweA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change single click instead of double click so it will work fine in mobile.

you welcome in advance :) .